# Custom Java 8 Collector

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, collectors

I would like to check how to implement a custom Collector.

Say, I have a need to do some

(1) analysis on words like alphabet-frequency map and 
(2) ability to combine 2 results to get a single result.

```
class CharHistogram implements Collector<String, Map<Character, Integer>, Map<Character, Integer>> {



    public static CharHistogram toCharHistogram(){
        return new CharHistogram();
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<Character, Integer>> supplier() {
        SysOut.print("supplier invoked");
        return HashMap::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Map<Character, Integer>, String> accumulator() {
        SysOut.print("accumulator invoked");
        return (map, val) -> {
            SysOut.print(val +" processed");
            char[] characters = val.toCharArray();
            for (char character : characters) {
                int count = 1;
                if (map.containsKey(character)) {
                    count = map.get(character);
                    count++;
                }
                map.put(character, count);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<Character, Integer>> combiner() {
        SysOut.print("combiner invoked");
        return (map1, map2) -> {
            SysOut.print(map1+" merged to "+map2);
            map2.forEach((k, v) -> map1.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2));
            return map1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Map<Character, Integer>, Map<Character, Integer>> finisher() {
        SysOut.print("finisher invoked");
        return Function.identity();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH, Characteristics.UNORDERED));
    }

}
```

Client code:

```
CharHistogram charStatsState = CharHistogram.toCharHistogram();

Map<Character, Integer> charCountMap = Arrays.asList("apple","orange","orange").stream().collect(charStatsState);
SysOut.print(charCountMap);
charCountMap = Arrays.asList("pears","pears","orange").stream().collect(charStatsState);
SysOut.print(charCountMap);
```

Output:

```
[main]: supplier invoked
[main]: accumulator invoked
[main]: combiner invoked
[main]: apple processed
[main]: orange processed
[main]: orange processed
[main]: {p=2, a=3, r=2, e=3, g=2, l=1, n=2, o=2}
[main]: supplier invoked
[main]: accumulator invoked
[main]: combiner invoked
[main]: pears processed
[main]: pears processed
[main]: orange processed
[main]: {p=2, a=3, r=3, s=2, e=3, g=1, n=1, o=1}
```

I don't see the combiner nor the finisher getting called and I believe these needs to be designed correctly to achieve what I'm looking for.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

A possible approach to support streams and combiner. The below code doesn't work though.

```
class CharStreamHistogram implements Function<String, Map<Character, Integer>>{

    private int totalCharactersRead;
    private Map<Character, Integer> histogram;

    public int getTotalCharactersRead() {
        return totalCharactersRead;
    }
    public Map<Character, Integer> getHistogram() {
        return histogram;
    }
    public void setHistogram(Map<Character, Integer> histogram) {
        this.histogram = histogram;
    }
    public void setTotalCharactersRead(int totalCharactersRead) {
        this.totalCharactersRead = totalCharactersRead;
    }

    public Map<Character, Integer> combine(Map<Character, Integer>  map2) {
        Map<Character, Integer> map1 = this.histogram;
        map2.forEach((k, v) -> map1.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2));
        return map2;
    }


    @Override
    public Map<Character, Integer> apply(String val) {
        char[] characters = val.toCharArray();
        totalCharactersRead += characters.length;
        for (char character : characters) {
            int count = 1;
            if (histogram.containsKey(character)) {
                count = histogram.get(character);
                count++;
            }
            histogram.put(character, count);
        }
        return histogram;
    }

} 

public static <T> Collector<T, ?, CharStreamHistogram> summarizeCharStream(
             CharStreamHistogram histogram) { //TODO: is this correct?
        Collector charStatsState = new Collector<String, CharStreamHistogram, CharStreamHistogram>() {

            @Override
            public Supplier<CharStreamHistogram> supplier() {
                return CharStreamHistogram::new;
            }

            @Override
            public BiConsumer<CharStreamHistogram, String> accumulator() {
                //TODO: What to do here?
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public BinaryOperator<CharStreamHistogram> combiner() {
                BinaryOperator binaryOperator = (l, r) -> {
                    l.combine(r); //TODO: Something like this?
                };
                return binaryOperator;
            }

            @Override
            public Function<CharStreamHistogram, CharStreamHistogram> finisher() {
                //TODO: What to do here?
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Set<java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
                return Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED));
            }
        };
        return charStatsState;
    }
```

Comment: Your `Collector` should not have any state.  Your accumulator object should contain both `totalCharactersRead` and the map.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks. so for now I'll remove it. But I'll come to that later.

Answer (score 6):

Well you have declared `Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH` - which explicitly means that `finisher` will not be called, and the `combiner` will be called only in case of a parallel stream.

Comment: I didn't truly understand the role of `finisher()`. Is the above code correct for the use case.

Comment: Yes, other than the state in the collector.  Neither the combiner nor the finisher are necessary for this use case.

Comment: but i need the ability to combine 2 results. How do I do that?

Comment: @John you need that ability only when a parallel stream is in action, other than that I did not really understand your question here

Comment: I have made an edit. Should I go for such an approach?

Comment: @John this is rather confusing, if you want to create a collector like that, your definition should really be `public static <T> Collector<String, ?, Map<Character, Integer>> summarizeCharStream(){....}`

Comment: Basically this is what I'm trying. (1)  a way to collect statistics (2) a way to add new statistics to the existing one

Comment: @John why not make a mutable `Map` in such a case? `Map<Character, Long> map = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three")
                .stream()
                .flatMap(x -> x.chars().mapToObj(y -> (char) y))
                // .map(x -> Character.)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Function.identity(),
                        HashMap::new,
                        Collectors.counting()));`

Comment: Right but I don't then get to learn to write a custom Collector 

Comment: @John right, totally agreed, thus my previous comment that your collector should really have the definition `public static <T> Collector<String, ?, Map<Character, Integer>> summarizeCharStream(){....}` start from here - and see where you have issues

Comment: @John when you want to learn, how to write a custom collector, you still should adhere to the best practices, to learn these. First, there is no reason to ever implement `Collector` yourself. You can simply call `Collector.of(…)`, passing the three or four functions and optional characteristics. When you omit the finisher, `IDENTITY_FINISH` will be added automatically. Further, you show that you know `Map.merge` in the combiner function, so why don’t you use it in the accumulator too? And, don’t copy an entire string to a `char[]` array, just for the `for` loop. Use `string.chars().forEach(…)`